# Can a page in Django-CMS contain multiple records?

Tags: django-cms

I need to create pages on my (planned) website that each consist of multiple, independent entries records. (It's a famous quotes website - each page covers a specific topic, with multiple quotes and their authors listed for that topic.)

Is it straightforward with Django-CMS to implement this, with each quote/author being a separate database record (I need for them to be acted upon as individual entities, for purposes like voting). I'm thinking of using Django-CMS because of its categorization capabilities, built-in slug support, and because I'm merging in a Wordpress blog to the mix as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible and there's two approaches to it:

1) Write an Apphook [1] that manages those pages and displays the quotes from the database.
2) Write a Plugin [2] that displays a single (or multiple) quotes and add one or more of those plugins to the pages.

If you're not sure which one to choose, I recommend reading http://ojii.ch/post/apphooks-vs-plugins/

[1] http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/app_integration.html
[2] http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html